# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag? nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions library

Tags: android, android-permissions

While using

> nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions library: [Link](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions)

Getting error when I'm running app on Android device API Level > 20

It's non-activity class. MainApp.getmContext() return the Application context:

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    Permissions.check(MainApp.getmContext(), permissions, null/*rationale*/, null/*options*/, new PermissionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onGranted() {
            // do your task.
            Toast.makeText(MainApp.getmContext(), "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(MainApp.getmContext(), "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The error is coming on **Permissions.check** line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because of your MainApp.getmContext.  That is actually the application context.  You need an activity context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As, i was getting the context through Application extended class. But after passing activity context it's working.

Comment: How can i get the context of activity programmatically like I don't want that user can do set the context. As, I'm working on library and on that perspective i don't want that user can set the context his self.

Comment: @AliAzazAlam I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

We've to pass the Activity [on which you want to show the permissions] Context in permission argument:

```
public static void permissionGrant(Context mContext){
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    Permissions.check(mContext, permissions, null/*rationale*/, null/*options*/, new PermissionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onGranted() {
            // do your task.
            Toast.makeText(MainApp.getmContext(), "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(MainApp.getmContext(), "Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some devices, while starting new activity from service context, it is required to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the `Intent`. In order to do so, use the following object as the `options` parameter.

```
Options options = new Options().setCreateNewTask();
```

For more information, see [this issue](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions/issues/11) and [this pull request.](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions/pull/12)